# Fetch data from multiple MySQL tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

My two tables look like this:

```
       TABLE1                      TABLE2
+--------------------+      +--------------------+
|field1|field2|field3|  and |field2|field4|field5|
+--------------------+      +--------------------+
```

I am already running a SELECT query for TABLE1, and assorting all of the data into variables:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM TABLE1 WHERE field2 = 2";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($result);    
  if((!is_bool($result) || $result) && $num_rows) {
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
   $field1 = $row['field1'];
   $field2 = $row['field2'];
   $field3 = $row['field3'];
    }
  }
```

What I want to do is get the data from 'field4' on TABLE2 and add it to my variables. I would want to get field4 WHERE field2 = 2

Comment: This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2627083/php-fetch-rows-from-multiple-mysql-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.field4
FROM
  TABLE1 AS t1,
  TABLE2 AS t2
WHERE 
    t1.field2 = 2
  AND
    t1.field2 = t2.field2
```

You want to join the two table which can be done explicitly (using the [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/join.html) operator or one of its variants) our implicitly (by `SELECT`ing from multiple tables directly).

From your description, I suppose that you want to do the join where `field2` in the two tables have the same value (`2`).

---

*If* `TABLE2` will not always provide a valid join candidate but you still want the data from `TABLE1`, you should use a `LEFT JOIN` (giving `NULL` for `field4` where nothing matched):

```
SELECT
  t1.*,
  t2.field4
FROM
    TABLE1 AS t1
  LEFT JOIN
    TABLE2 AS t2
  ON
    t1.field2 = t2.field2
WHERE 
  t1.field2 = 2
```

Comment: @Jon McIntosh You're welcome :) Please consider closing the question (by accepting an answer) if your problem is solved.

Comment: What is the difference between Left Join and Normal fetching data from two tables?

Comment: @tisuchi As stated in my answer, the choice between outer join (`LEFT` / `RIGHT`) and "normal" (`JOIN` or multiple tables) relates to the desire for strictly joining rows vs. `NULL` substitutes on no-match. I suggest you take a look at the top answers for [Difference between INNER and OUTER joins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/difference-between-inner-and-outer-joins)

Answer (score 1):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a [`JOIN`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html):

```
SELECT TABLE1.*,TABLE2.field4 FROM TABLE1 JOIN TABLE2 ON TABLE1.field2=TABLE2.field2 WHERE TABLE1.field2=2;
```

Answer (score 0):

hi try the following as ur query.

It is not preferred all the time to use * in the select query

```
SELECT T1.field1,T1.field2,T1.field3, T2.field4 FROM TABLE1 AS T1 INNER JOIN TABLE2 AS T2 ON T1.field2=T2.field2 WHERE field2 = 2
```